# Calculating proportions based on conditions

Tags: r, data-manipulation

please see sample data below:

```
data <- data.frame(q1=c(3,4,5,2,1,2,4),
                   q2=c(3,4,4,5,4,3,2),
                   q3=c(2,3,2,3,1,2,3),
                   q4=c(3,4,4,4,4,5,5))
```

I would like to create a another column which shows the percent of 4/5 responses. The output I am hoping to get looks something like this. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
 q1 q2 q3 q4 percent
1  3  3  2  3    0.00
2  4  4  3  4    0.75
3  5  4  2  4    0.75
4  2  5  3  4    0.50
5  1  4  1  4    0.50
6  2  3  2  5    0.25
7  4  2  3  5    0.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rowMeans`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(percent = rowMeans(across(everything(), ~ .x %in% 4:5)))
```

-output

```
  q1 q2 q3 q4 percent
1  3  3  2  3    0.00
2  4  4  3  4    0.75
3  5  4  2  4    0.75
4  2  5  3  4    0.50
5  1  4  1  4    0.50
6  2  3  2  5    0.25
7  4  2  3  5    0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
data$percent = rowMeans(data>3)
```

Or

```
data$percent = apply(data, 1, \(x) mean(x %in% 4:5))

  q1 q2 q3 q4 percent
1  3  3  2  3    0.00
2  4  4  3  4    0.75
3  5  4  2  4    0.75
4  2  5  3  4    0.50
5  1  4  1  4    0.50
6  2  3  2  5    0.25
7  4  2  3  5    0.50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(q1=c(3,4,5,2,1,2,4),
                   q2=c(3,4,4,5,4,3,2),
                   q3=c(2,3,2,3,1,2,3),
                   q4=c(3,4,4,4,4,5,5))

percent_4_5 <- function(x) {
  (sum(x == 4) + sum(x == 5)) / length(x)
}
data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(percent = percent_4_5(c_across(starts_with("q")))) %>% ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution without using dplyr

```
library(magrittr)
data$percent <- (data > 3) %>% as.data.frame() %>% apply(., 1, mean)
```

True is considered as 1 and False is considered as 0 when counting.

Output:

```
q1 q2 q3 q4 percent
1  3  3  2  3    0.00
2  4  4  3  4    0.75
3  5  4  2  4    0.75
4  2  5  3  4    0.50
5  1  4  1  4    0.50
6  2  3  2  5    0.25
7  4  2  3  5    0.50
```